# Get all the divs, except the first from other page

Tags: jquery, ajax, get

So, i'm having trouble selecting divs that are not the first child.
This is the code:

```
$.get(pageToLoad, function(data){
        var postsContent = $(data).find(".post:not(:first)").get(0).outerHTML;
        $(".feedpost-lastreplys").prepend(postsContent);
});
```

Actually, this selects the .post that are not the first child from other page, but this only retrieve the first .post that matches (the second .post on page).
How can i select all the divs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appear to be selecting single element by providing `0` as parameter to `.get()` . Try removing call to `.get()` `.outerHTML`

```
   $.get(pageToLoad, function(data) {
     var postsContent = $(data).find(".post:not(:first)");
     $(".feedpost-lastreplys").prepend(postsContent);
   })
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/a8509tqh/